# Custom unmarshalling json combining two fields

Tags: json, go

I have some json I want to unmarshal into the following struct

```
type Activity struct {
    Start  time.Time `json:"start"`
    End    time.Time `json:"end"`
}
```

Works fine if the json is properly formated.
However, sometimes the "end" fields exists but is just an empty string

```
{
        "start": "2020-06-02T07:48:35.911Z",
        "end":""
}
```

In this case I want Activity.End = Activity.Start

Is there anyway I can do this by implementing UnmarshalJSON or do I have to use a map?

Comment: "Is there anyway I can do this by implementing UnmarshalJSON". Yes, this is what UnmarshalJSON is for.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/ZAXvZ9Fflhw

Comment: That's what I was wanting. Thanks @mkopriva. I was missing the  ```var v struct {
  Start time.Time
  End   json.RawMessage``` intermediate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on suggestion of mkopriva:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Activity struct {
    Start time.Time `json:"start"`
    End   time.Time `json:"end"`
}

func (a *Activity) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var v struct {
        Start time.Time
        End   json.RawMessage
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(v.End) > 0 && string(v.End) != `""` {
        a.Start = v.Start
        return json.Unmarshal([]byte(v.End), &a.End)
    }
    
    a.Start = v.Start
    a.End = v.Start
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var data1 = []byte(`{"start": "2020-06-02T07:48:35.911Z","end":"2021-10-15T07:48:35.911Z"}`)
    var data2 = []byte(`{"start": "2020-06-02T07:48:35.911Z","end":""}`)

    var a Activity
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data1, &a); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data2, &a); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a)
}
```

Output:

```
{Start:2020-06-02 07:48:35.911 +0000 UTC End:2021-10-15 07:48:35.911 +0000 UTC}
{Start:2020-06-02 07:48:35.911 +0000 UTC End:2020-06-02 07:48:35.911 +0000 UTC}
```